# how to divide table row into 2 and display into page

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have 20 array data from my DB and I decided to put it into a table to display it on my page..

```
<tbody>                                         
        <?php for ($n=0; $n < 10; $n++) { ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $n+1; 
                $prescription_array=explode('/',$new_array2[$n]);                                               
            ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php 

            for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
                echo "<font size='5'>".$prescription_array[$i]."</font>";
                $x++;
            }
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

I use a for loop to limit the data that is being displayed cuz if I tried to display all data when I print the data it overlaps on my header and footer.. so my problem is how to display the remaining data to the next page.. I can't find any better solution for this.

```
$sql = "SELECT prescriptions FROM tblprescriptions WHERE `ID`='$ID' AND `appID`='$appID' ";
            $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();

if($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $prescriptions = $row['prescriptions'];
}

return @$prescriptions;
```

This is the query I use to get the data from my db..
[image]
This what I want to achieve but I can only get the first page and I don't have any idea how to display the remaining array... I tried a diff approach to display header and footer using thead and tfoot but no luck... I'm using chrome; any idea on how to display the remaining data?...

`amen (amen)      50mg -- 20pcs. -- 5x per day -- morning noon and evening -- 5 days1/,   yes (yes)      50mg -|- #50 -|- 5x per day -|- morning noon and evening -|- 10 days/,  51 (51)      51mg | #51 | 5x per week | morning noon and evening | 10 days/, bio (gesic) || 50mg || #50 || 5x per week || morning noon and evening || 10 days/, biogesic (paracetamol) | | 250mg | | #20 | | 5x per week | | morning noon and evening | | 14 days/, mefenamic (paracetamol)_100mg_#10_3x per week_morning noon and evening_10 days/, biogesic (paracetamol) = 250mg = #20 = 5x per week = morning noon and evening = 14 days/, bio (tamol) :: 50mg :: #50 :: 5x per week :: morning noon and evening :: 14 days/, bio (tamol) \ 50mg \ #50 \ 5x per week \ morning noon and evening \ 14 days/, bio (tamol) + 50mg + #50 + 5x per week + morning noon and evening + 14 days/, amen (amen)      50mg -- 20pcs. -- 5x per day -- morning noon and evening -- 5 days1/,   yes (yes)      50mg -|- #50 -|- 5x per day -|- morning noon and evening -|- 10 days/,  51 (51)      51mg | #51 | 5x per week | morning noon and evening | 10 days/, bio (gesic) || 50mg || #50 || 5x per week || morning noon and evening || 10 days/, biogesic (paracetamol) | | 250mg | | #20 | | 5x per week | | morning noon and evening | | 14 days/, mefenamic (paracetamol)_100mg_#10_3x per week_morning noon and evening_10 days/, biogesic (paracetamol) = 250mg = #20 = 5x per week = morning noon and evening = 14 days/, bio (tamol) :: 50mg :: #50 :: 5x per week :: morning noon and evening :: 14 days/, bio (tamol) \ 50mg \ #50 \ 5x per week \ morning noon and evening \ 14 days/, bio (tamol) + 50mg + #50 + 5x per week + morning noon and evening + 14 days/,`

this is the sample data that is being returned from my db.. that is the reason why i use explode to separate this data into array data.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You have a problem printing a table from a web page? I do not understand your question, but I think that you're taking the wrong approach. Web pages normally don't have printable pages. The browser will create printable pages from a web page. The way to guide the browser is by using CSS: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet & http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_for_print_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You have `20` records in database, you want to `page 1` display from firstst record to tenth record and `page 2` display from eleventh record to twentieth recode.

With `page 1`, you add for SQL `LIMIT 0, 10`.

With `page 2`, you add for SQL `LIMIT 10, 10`.

You can understand the following: `LIMIT $start, $limit`

`$start` is the starting position in the database

`$limit` is the number of records you want to retrieve

So, I example for You pass the `page` parameter at URL. You get `page` to calculate

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
if ($page < 1) $page = 1;
```

Now, you will calculate `$start`

```
$limit = 10;
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
```

So, You have SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT prescriptions FROM tblprescriptions WHERE `ID`='{$ID}' AND `appID`='{$appID}' LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";
```

Good look

Comment: i think limit wont work on my problem.. the reason why i use for loop is bc the data that is being returned is an array.. that is the reason why i use explode to separate those data .. the returned value from the database is only one... so i dont think that limit is going to work on sql query.

Comment: @LionSmith , You want get all data for one time only, and show data for many page. Is that you want to?

Comment: let me update my question and give you the sample of the data that is being returned

Comment: @LionSmith , i will update on this ask, you view that is solution you want?

Comment: what i want to do is to display all data when i print but 10 data per page.

Comment: @LionSmith so, How did you go to page 2?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use LIMIT in your query statement to get the desired number of rows per page. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html <-- see LIMIT clause.

Adding extra info:

Let's say you can show 10 rows in a page and you have 20 rows in the BD table. You need to code your logic in a way that gathers the first 10 rows of the table for the first page:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [filtering here] LIMIT 0, 10
```

Then for the second page:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [filtering here] LIMIT 11, 10
```

and so on for more pages. See Mr Ken answer for more details.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16238969)

Comment: @Ajay you're absolutely right. I've added some extra info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_slice() to achieve your result.

```
$arr1 = array_slice($prescriptions,0,10);
$arr2 = array_slice($prescriptions,10,20);
```